# NuxtJS 2 + Vite + @nuxtjs/i18n error "does not provide an export named 'hasProtocol"

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, vite, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I have a problem with the @nuxtjs/i18n package when I want to use it with nuxt2 + vite. I get the error shown below when activating the project.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/@nuxtjs/i18n/node_modules/ufo/dist/index.cjs?import' does not provide an export named 'hasProtocol' (at plugin.utils.js:2:10)
```

#### nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    '@nuxtjs/i18n'
  ],
  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        name: 'Polish',
        code: 'pl',
        iso: 'pl-PL',
        file: 'pl.json'
      },
      {
        name: 'English',
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        file: 'en.json'
      }
    ],
    langDir: 'locales/',
    defaultLocale: 'en'

  },
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "operator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js",
    "lintfix": "yarn lint:js --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@braid/vue-formulate": "^2.5.3",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.3.1",
    "@nuxtjs/recaptcha": "^1.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "ufo": "^1.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^11.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "nuxt-vite": "^0.2.4",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

I will be very grateful for any hint, because I have not found a solution to my problem on the Internet

Comment: Do you manage to make something work ? I saw [this comment](https://github.com/nuxt-modules/i18n/discussions/1334#discussioncomment-2322287), but I'm not able to make it work as it says.